# Javascript forEach loop with current index after new element was deleted

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the updated index of the forEach loop after an element has been removed from the DOM.

Here is my current script ...

```
function delete(){
 var elm = document.querySelectorAll('.divs');
 elm.forEach(function(item, index){
  item.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  document.querySelectorAll('.divs')[index].remove();
 });
}
```

after the element was removed the calculations for the index are incorrect.
how can I get the index of the clicked item after one or more items has been removed?

Comment: The `index` will be the initital index it was set to when the delete function first run, once one is deleted it will not work correctly. Have you tried `e.target.remove()`?

Comment: or even `item.remove()`

Comment: You can add a dataset on a element and use that to do your calculation? what calculation are you trying to do anyways?

Comment: @RubenSmn `e.target.remove()` removes the exact element that was clicked. `e.currentTarget.remove()` is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a very simple solution, but I don't know if you can accept it!

Node list in DOM is always live, if you refer to it as a variable, this variable is active. Check here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

I propose you just to hide it!

```js
listDivs1();
deleteDiv1();

function listDivs1() {
  let ht = '';
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('#method1 .divs');
  els.forEach(function(e, index) {
    ht += 'index: ' + index + ' - ' + e.innerHTML + '<br>';
  });
  document.querySelector('.elements1').innerHTML = ht;
}

function deleteDiv1() {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('#method1 .divs');
  els.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      document.querySelectorAll('.divs')[index].remove();
      listDivs1();
    });
  });
}


listDivs2();
deleteDiv2();

function listDivs2() {
  let ht = '';
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('#method2 .divs');
  els.forEach(function(e, index) {
    ht += 'index: ' + index + ' - ' + e.innerHTML + '<br>';
  });
  document.querySelector('.elements2').innerHTML = ht;
}

function deleteDiv2() {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('#method2 .divs');
  els.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.remove();
      listDivs2();
    });
  });
}



listDivs3();
deleteDiv3();

function listDivs3() {
  let ht = '';
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('#method3 .divs');
  els.forEach(function(e, index) {
    if (e.style.display !== 'none') {
      ht += 'index: ' + index + ' - ' + e.innerHTML + '<br>';
    }
  });
  document.querySelector('.elements3').innerHTML = ht;
}
window.addEventListener('load', listDivs3);

function deleteDiv3() {
  let els = document.querySelectorAll('#method3 .divs');
  els.forEach(function(item, index) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.style.display = 'none';
      listDivs3();
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  grid-row-gap: 0px;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<h1>your delete</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div id="method1">
    <div class="divs">div 0</div>
    <div class="divs">div 1</div>
    <div class="divs">div 2</div>
    <div class="divs">div 3</div>
    <div class="divs">div 4</div>
    <div class="divs">div 5</div>
    <div class="divs">div 6</div>
    <div class="divs">div 7</div>
    <div class="divs">div 8</div>
    <div class="divs">div 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="elements1"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h1>e.target</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div id="method2">
    <div class="divs">div 0</div>
    <div class="divs">div 1</div>
    <div class="divs">div 2</div>
    <div class="divs">div 3</div>
    <div class="divs">div 4</div>
    <div class="divs">div 5</div>
    <div class="divs">div 6</div>
    <div class="divs">div 7</div>
    <div class="divs">div 8</div>
    <div class="divs">div 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="elements2"></div>
</div>
<hr>
<h1>display none</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div id="method3">
    <div class="divs">div 0</div>
    <div class="divs">div 1</div>
    <div class="divs">div 2</div>
    <div class="divs">div 3</div>
    <div class="divs">div 4</div>
    <div class="divs">div 5</div>
    <div class="divs">div 6</div>
    <div class="divs">div 7</div>
    <div class="divs">div 8</div>
    <div class="divs">div 9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="elements3"></div>
</div>
```

In the snippet you 2 columns, the one with the divs to click, and second one with index and div content to check after each delete the result.

So with your function, index and div disconnect. With e.target same. With display none, it's working because nothing has been really removed, only "visually" removed. If you have other functions iterating through all those divs you'll have to exclude the display none like in listDivs3 function.

If this display none doesn't suit you, The only way would be:

- store all div in temporary variable
- remove the one you need
- remove the node list
- put the divs from the new list
- re add your even listener

Comment: `NodeList` isn't always *live*. `document.querySelectorAll` returns *static* collection. You can read about it in the link you provided.

Comment: @marzelin, sorry I didn't express what I was thinking clearly. My fault. You're right.

Comment: "*I propose you just to hide it!*" - bad solution. It may appear to work in this simple example, but will ultimately fail.

Comment: You're right Bergi, I wrote "if that's ok with you". I don't know complexity of the page. Otherwise solution is longer and more complex as explained at the end.

Comment: Thank you so much for the display none worked as it should be. I don't know why I haven't thought of that. Awesome and helpful answer!